# Punctuation in direct quotation

Tags: punctuation

I have a hard time deciding. Which of the two punctuations is correct?

"So what?," you may ask.

"So what?" you may ask.

Or is there a better way to set the punctuation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was taught that a comma is never needed for quotations ending in "?" or "!" and to use the second. If the quote ends in a period, replace the period with a comma, though.

I've been trying to find a source in case you don't wanna take my word for it. :)